# A and B are independent under$\mathbb{P}$ but not under $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

As the title, how to construct such an example that 2 events from the same measurable
space ($\Omega$,$\mathscr{A}$) are independent under probability measure $\mathbb{P}$ but not independent under $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: Suppose you make the events constant (deterministic) with respect to $\mathbb P$ but not $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: @GEdgar in fact I'm still not clear. Isn't probability measure a function? So if a event in function a is determined, how can it be undetermined in function b?

Comment: The experiment consists of rolling a tetrahedral die with faces marked $1,3,4,12$ and the outcome is the number showing on the bottom face when the die comes to rest. Thus, $\Omega=\{1,3,4,12\}$ and we take $\mathscr{A}= 2^{\Omega}$. Let $A=\{3,12\}$ and $B=\{4,12\}$ denote the events that the outcome is a multiple of $3$ and $4$ respectively. $\mathbb P$ assigns equal probability $\frac 14$ to the four outcomes, and $A$ and $B$ are independent events. $\mathbb Q$ assigns probability $\frac 12$ to $1$ and $\frac 16$ to the other outcomes, and $A$ and $B$ are not independent under $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: @DilipSarwate so it is just a mathematical trick to assign different probability to the events and let P(A$\bigcap$B)=P(A)P(B) and another not equal?

Comment: Am I the only one who is extremely confused by usage of $\mathbb Q$ to refer to a probability measure?

Answer (score 1):

To get an intuitive feel for this, don't get too bogged down in the algebra to begin with. If we take the simple example of two coin tosses, note that even if we declare that both coins are fair, we still have some freedom in specifying their joint distributions. In particular, we could declare that the coin toss outcomes are independent of one another, or we could declare that the outcome of one determines the other (e.g. the second coin always has the same outcome as the first, or always has the opposite outcome).

Mathematically, specifying the joint distribution in the above example is equivalent to specifying a probability measure on the measurable space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$, where $\Omega = \{HH,TH,HT,TT\}$ is the sample space of outcomes of the two coin tosses, and $\mathcal{F}=2^{\Omega}$ is the set of subsets of the sample space. So, as described in the first paragraph, we can specify a probability measure on the measurable space which implies independence of the two coin tosses (and that the two coin tosses are fair), and we can specify a probability measure that implies that one coin toss exactly determines the outcome of the other (and also that the two coin tosses are fair).

Under the first of these probabilities, the random variables $X_1, X_2 : \Omega \rightarrow \{H,T\}$ which give the outcome of the first (resp. second) coin toss are independent, and under the second, they are perfectly correlated.

Answer (score 1):

Fleshing out my "deterministic" hint.

Let $\Omega = \{7,8\}$.  Let events $A = B = \{7\}$.  If $\mathbb P$ is defined as: $\mathbb P\{7\} = 1$, $\mathbb P\{8\}=0$, then $A$ is deterministic, or non-random.  Event $A$ happens a.s. and $A$ is independent of $B$.  But of course if you define $\mathbb Q$ with $\mathbb Q\{7\} = 1/2, \mathbb Q\{8\}=1/2$ (or, indeed, anything other than $1$ and $0$), then $A$ is not independent of $B$.

Answer (score 1):

I will borrow from, but give a slightly different twist, to the answer given by @Mark.

Consider the  measurable space $(\Omega,\mathscr F)$, where
$\Omega = \{HH, HT, TH, TT\}$ is the sample space of outcomes of the two tosses
of the same coin, and $\mathscr F = 2^\Omega$  is the set of subsets of the sample space.

Let $A = \{HH, HT\}$, $B=\{HT,TH\}$, and $C=\{HH,TH\}$ be three events which
we can describe colloquially as "Heads on first toss", "Exactly one Heads in two
tosses" and "Heads on second toss" respectively. In what follows, let us consider only those probability measures that assign probabilities $p^2, p(1-p), (1-p)p, (1-p)^2$ to $HH, HT, TH, TT$ respectively. Note that $p \in [0,1]$. These
measures are, of course, those corresponding to *independent* tosses of a
coin that turns up Heads with probability $p$.

- We have that $P(A)=P(C) = p$
  and $P(A\cap C) = p^2$ and thus $A$ and $C$ are independent events in *all* such
  probability measures.  The coin tosses are independent, as noted above.
- $P(B) = 2p(1-p)$ and $P(A\cap B) = p(1-p)$ and thus
  $$P(A\cap B) - P(A)P(B) = p(1-p) - p\cdot 2p(1-p) = p(1-p)(1-2p).$$
  Thus, we see that $P(A\cap B)$ equals $P(A)P(B)$ (and so $A$ and $B$ are independent events) only
  for *three* probability measures: those for which $p$ is $0$, $\frac 12$, or
  $1$.

Thus, whether $A$ and $B$ are independent events or dependent events
is determined solely by the value we assign to $p$.

Comment: Is that mean we can let $P(A)P(B)=P(A\bigcap B)$ first and solve out the probability p which let A and B independent?